# AsyncTestZoneSpec is needed for the async - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, angular-test

The application was built on `Angular v4` and was gradually updated with every release up until now. Currently we're on `Angular v7` and finally the CEO has agreed to write unit test while it wasn't the case before.

I just created a simple spec to just get started with the tests and start implementing it throughout the project but got stuck for two days with the following error:

> AsyncTestZoneSpec is needed for the async() test helper but could not be >found. Please make sure that your environment includes zone.js/dist/async->test.js

While googling for the above error, I found some answers but that was related to `Wallaybyjs` but rather specific to Angular.

I've tried to reproduce the issue with the brand new installation of the `angular` project but couldn't really. This might be issue with some dependencies required to be missing to run tests on `Angular 7`.

Following is the `test.ts` file:

```
// This file is required by karma.conf.js and loads recursively all the .spec and framework files

import 'zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone';
import 'zone.js/dist/proxy.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/sync-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch';
import 'zone.js/dist/async-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/fake-async-test';
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

// Unfortunately there's no typing for the `__karma__` variable. Just declare it as any.
declare const __karma__: any;
declare const require: any;

// Prevent Karma from running prematurely.
__karma__.loaded = function () {};

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
// Finally, start Karma to run the tests.
__karma__.start();
```

and `Package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "frontend",
    "version": "0.1.2-7",
    "appVersion": "2.104",
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e",
        "build-staging": "bash build-staging.sh",
        "build-production": "bash build-production.sh",
        "compodoc": "npx compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.9",
        "@angular/animations": "7.0.3",
        "@angular/common": "7.0.3",
        "@angular/compiler": "7.0.3",
        "@angular/core": "7.0.3",
        "@angular/forms": "7.0.3",
        "@angular/http": "7.0.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "7.0.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.0.3",
        "@angular/router": "7.0.3",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.9.0",
        "@mobiscroll/angular": "^4.7.3",
        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
        "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
        "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
        "angular2-virtual-scroll": "^0.4.16",
        "core-js": "^2.6.9",
        "moment": "^2.22.2",
        "ng-block-ui": "^2.1.5",
        "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
        "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^7.2.0",
        "ngx-lazy-load-images": "^1.3.1",
        "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
        "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.2",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.29"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "7.0.5",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.15",
        "@angular/language-service": "7.0.3",
        "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.9",
        "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.16",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
        "@types/node": "^10.14.10",
        "codelyzer": "^4.4.2",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.3.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
        "karma": "^4.1.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
        "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.5",
        "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
        "protractor": "^5.4.2",
        "ts-node": "~7.0.1",
        "tslint": "~5.7.0",
        "typescript": "3.1.6"
    }
}
```

Following is the `component` spec:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { InsuranceComponent } from './insurance.component';
import { CartModule } from '../../cart/cart.module';
import { SharedModule } from '../../shared/shared.module';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MbscModule } from '@mobiscroll/angular';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { PipeModule } from '../../pipe/pipe.module';
import { InfiniteScrollModule } from 'ngx-infinite-scroll';
import { InsuranceRoutingModule } from '../insurance-routing/insurance-routing.module';
import { InsuranceSearchItemComponent } from '../insurance-search-item/insurance-search-item.component';
// tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
import { InsuranceSearchItemDetailsComponent } from '../insurance-search-item/insurance-search-item-details/insurance-search-item-details.component';

describe('Insurance Component', () => {
    let component: InsuranceComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<InsuranceComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                CartModule,
                SharedModule,
                CommonModule,
                MbscModule,
                FormsModule,
                NgbModule,
                PipeModule,
                InfiniteScrollModule,
                InsuranceRoutingModule
            ],
            declarations: [InsuranceComponent, InsuranceSearchItemComponent, InsuranceSearchItemDetailsComponent]
        }).compileComponents();

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(InsuranceComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    }));

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated alot.
Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following command was likely deprecated:

```
ng test --main somecomponent.spec.ts
```

Instead, use:

```
ng test
```

To just run a specific `spec` instead of `all`, prefix your `describe` and `it` block with `f`:

```
fdescribe('whatever', () => {})
```

Answer (score 30):

I was getting this error after Angular 11 upgrade.

This line must be the first line in test.ts, before all other imports:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing'; // zone-testing needs to be first import!
```

Comment: Confirmed! Since today we had this issue, upgrading our package-lock. Moving the import to be the first resolved the issue. We had to /* tslint:disable */ the file, because we have automatic import ordering otherwise. The upgrade changed dependencies from 11.0.2 to 11.0.3.

Comment: In my case I had to additionally put this import as my first one in that file (before importing getTestBed etc).

Comment: This was exactly my issue! I also had to disable organize imports in VS code, it kept reorganizing the imports to put this last and causing issues.

Comment: for me, after adding this,  running the test now shows:  `cannot find module ''zone.js/dist/zone-testing'

Answer (score 5):

I use this command in order to test one file only:

`ng test --include somecomponent.spec.ts`

You are going to have issues with the `--main` option as @clean-code has stated.

Comment: `ng test --include '**/somecomponent.spect.ts'` wfm.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with with the spectator testing framework.

The solution was, to import jest-preset-angular before the spectator imports.

**wrong:**

```js
import { defineGlobalsInjections } from '@ngneat/spectator';
import 'jest-preset-angular';
```

**correct:**

```js
import 'jest-preset-angular';
import { defineGlobalsInjections } from '@ngneat/spectator';
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue but with `jest` testing framework.

After you removed all the `karma` and `jasmine` related stuff and installed `jest` related staff you could have a similar error

```
    zone-testing.js is needed for the async() test helper but could not be found.
        Please make sure that your environment includes zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js
```

And here it is my `setup-jest.ts` file

```
import 'jest-preset-angular';
import 'jest-extended';
```

When I changed one of the imports in the file `setup-jest.ts` to this

```
import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest';
import 'jest-extended';
```

Everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

To use async() functionality, you need to import zone-testing.
Try importing zone-testing package into your test.ts file.

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing'
```

[Refer this link - Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/testing)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the issue was with the command `ng test --main abc.component.spec.ts` and when I run just `ng test` then it worked